# VBscript activeX Internet Explorer object alternative

Tags: linux, google-chrome, firefox, vbscript, activex

I need a Linux alternative to browser manipulation. In Windows I would use a `VBscript` to do this via Internet Explorer object, but in Linux I don't have either of those.

Is there any other script like environment for Linux that can manipulate FireFox or Chrome? I need to emulate a user using the browser and retrieve date from sites the 'user' accesses.

`curl` is not appropriate, because I need javascript as well. Basically I need the script to see the same thing that a 'real' user would see.

Comment: I need to emulate a user using the browser and retrive date from sites the 'user' accesses

Comment: Curl is not good, beacuse I need javascript as well, basicly I need the script to see the same thing that a real user would see

Comment: No need to thank me- editing to improve questions and answers is [expected from users](http://superuser.com/help/behavior) :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to automate browser interaction

alternatively you can bypass the browser and access the data directly by using web scraping - e.g. in python there is [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Comment: although selenium is good, I guess there is no real alternative to VBscript